# The empty set in Ackermann set theory

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $A$ denote Ackermann set theory, as laid out e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory). It is a standard result due to Levy and Reinhardt that $A$ and $ZF$ are mutually interpretable in conservative extensions of one-another.

> How do we see that the empty class is a set in $A$?

Despite scanning the [relevant](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2964757?read-now=1&seq=2) [papers](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272681/1-s2.0-S0003484300X00502/1-s2.0-0003484370900112/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEL%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCVF86L3PYX%2BmvGGWBUzlk%2BMVAh%2FUtNe%2F2xQDS5zwfqLAIgMZwn8HdNRRN7ew7e5XDDq2FCeqdWB4KIk6%2Fqp8wEwfAq2wQImP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDLf4Bln%2Fhaha2cCkpiqvBJ04KysoVxvWP0fKhnHWr7DHXVyPACoQBPNzR0cOY4vldZd05jMaacZmUhLsdFzzXUEJkaxP7J0EQNR2Awg2%2F2wXTy3abGMx6sk%2Fz4NYeY%2FYPd%2BWZ9KY7xZw8uHosdcZWNIZ3qpa24ZMk2DAmTzw5YOlQWNYZGhGu1eSTac0ENVx41J50nDQ9rrOCIY%2FGzXrBqh3OZ7Sa3QIa%2BaIuTVZvEZh8Av860wCX9IkygIo0AFn1C%2BJwH2FfhdW%2FwUlJm7oYQQuzH1SxWAl7RKha2QJGFsli4D6Q835oQKChYVFgZ8qLcmi1iLNZYQ%2FWiVdxn4hqfqCNAZaPMINX2hkba6m7pcp8eT8WCGCun1wcr1kC2JBUko0Q8rmkNT8uQrlv%2BR6QeLJP7ZWy9CfCvJDbVSXqsWIqIiC%2B4LM4pcrL9vP9%2B%2F29t9WWhkfaoYvK0BP8y6WzwuT%2FmJX09SIrCVXTfBsrWwvBtZw4b0skkkw1wO9z5rfwFi3wXp0Q%2BBSpGDP6qh1UvNNXdoyZy2Vurz5o9E0bMusS6x5o2nSzuAIf9r9y6%2B8K2p2GS1qs42J3TGe223oYjW0VGIrBjTHxLcs6CQwIUjsgva7YAbQLCabsaeld1O4grP4a1nUdzw%2FSBYpVlxrPkXwzmK1ebdq%2Bd%2FI5GdhJHLvkNZJcffvkG3Lks7KVP8YqEPjaofwaEAPsJKPpe4Rsw44PwulPDxohADXF0qIQacGoETMC3lOPrvFA3OwTUkwi4eGlAY6qQGYSq5%2Feqa%2FiEAO%2B4IN7pq%2FARE32lXyuyCysPGO%2FRkP%2FyiEvaV4%2BqRM111xU%2BJWWPxUCRe7lic3rkEWc%2Ft4yZ7cw2PwuoeZSGTsLSuWsFEObzSrcXS3DDmq7R37FQt2IjIfn5tz95BlZKnzFVoOmq7BR9OXng0o08LqoBMFMWcer3CdELRe4xPeI%2FuivjOD30w8jy%2F8opssZqviVsMq1bbSvRn6O9JuZS%2By&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220515T233526Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSTKQC36I%2F20220515%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0cd0fec412e470659cdfa4bf279c2bdd860d43c101b3417deeadb70e3c999661&hash=64acf22d7e9020e73583a1aa2a7c69ead138dc0e8ada0c3f4a45cfb130392bf7&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0003484370900112&tid=spdf-42a8afe8-7a90-4433-8235-dd8af648c432&sid=0ddd9aa381fae1491f29cd09d93f02d99847gxrqa&type=client&ua=4d51020107570557580b&rr=70bfb0a68e2e7ad4) I seem unable to find a simple argument laying out how $\emptyset\in\mathbb{V}$. Naively, my thought was to consider the predicate $$\phi\equiv\ "x\ \text{is a set}\wedge x\neq x"$$ and take $\emptyset$ to be the set guaranteed by the reflection schema (axiom $3$ above) together with $\phi$, but I am concerned that by writing '$x$ is a set' in the definition of $\phi$ I am implicitly allowing $\mathbb{V}$ to appear, since this is equivalent to $x\in\mathbb{V}$ -- this would obviously prevent us from defining $\emptyset$ in this fashion (unless I am misunderstanding what it means for a constant symbol to 'be a parameter' in a predicate).

Does this approach work, or is some other trick required? Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're overthinking the reflection scheme. Just use the formula $F(x)\equiv x\not=x$. Then:

- We trivially have $\forall x(F(x)\rightarrow x\in V)$, since no $x$ at all satisfies $F$.
- Consequently, reflection applies, and we get $\{x:F(x)\}\in V$ as desired.

Comment: Nice, I was literally on my way back to the computer to ask if this was one of those 'vacuous implication' things. Thanks as always Noah.